# Is it legal to stop my ISP from throttling my connection in EU?

Tags: internet

Hello recently I read online several articles that say that my ISP might be throttling my internet connection. Though I dont know if they indeed are throttling my connection but in any case I whould like to block them, is it legal (I live in the EU)? The command that is supposed to do that is this: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="StopThrottling" dir=in action=block remoteip=173.194.55.0/24,206.111.0.0/16 enable=yes`.

Comment: First of all, the rule you propose there would block you from commenting to one server. Second: **read your ISP contract** - they might be explicitly allowed to throttle your connection because you agreed to it.

Comment: Note that nothing you can do on your end can change how your ISP handles your traffic.  Unsure of where you are, but in many (all?) places internet is sold at (essentially) a maximum speed, so "throttled" is the default state (this is separate from "speed downgraded after x downloaded).